# How to have sub ordered lists correctly

Tags: html

I'm not sure I understand the logistics of this.  Basically I wanted to make a simple listing on a web blog that looks like:

```
1.  item1
    a.  item2
2.  item3
    a.  item4
    b.  item5
3.  item6
```

And so on, basically a master list ordered numerically, with child lists under each master item that are `lower-alpha` ordered.

I achieved this effect by using this HTML markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>item1</li>
    <ol>
        <li>item2</li>
    </ol>   
    <li>item3</li>
    <ol>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
    </ol>
    <li>item6</li>
</ol>
```

With this small CSS rule:

```
ol ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; } /* sub ordered lists */
```

This issue I had was that according to the w3c validator:

> Element ol not allowed as child of element ol in this context.

I think this problem ought have a very simple solution, I wasn't able to find one, and I'm not sure I follow why `ol` cannot be a child of `ol`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>item1
        <ol>
            <li>item2</li>
        </ol>
    </li> 
</ol>
```

You need to put the sublist *inside* the list item for the top level.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to control your sub-ordered list, either with CSS, or HTML. You almost were achieving the effect you want, to get something like this:

```
1.  item1
    a.  item2
2.  item3
    a.  item4
    b.  item5
3.  item6
```

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>item1
        <ol>
            <li>item2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>item3
        <ol>
            <li>item4</li>
            <li>item5</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>item6</li>
</ol>
```

And your CSS should look like this:

```
ol li{ list-style-type:decimal; } /* sub ordered lists level 1 */
ol li ol li { list-style-type: lower-alpha; } /* sub ordered lists level 2 */
```

You can also [read more about a similar question here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14238/numbered-list-with-subclauses)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your ol needs to be in an li:

```
<ol>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>item2</li>
        </ol> 
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I read this one first and got confused, it needs to be inside the `li` of item1 to achieve desired presentation.